# How do I make sure string does not contain colon using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing validation regex in c# - basically need to ensure that property does not have ":" in it. I'm total newbee with regex. This is what I have and it doesn't seem to work.. I read beginners FAQ on regex and this is what I came up with `"[^:]"`

```
[StringLengthVerifier(MaxValue = 25, IsRequired = true, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MEMUser_UserName")]
        [RegexVerifier("User Name", @"[^:]", ErrorMessage = "User name cannot contain colons")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By enclosing the character class with the string/line boundary meta characters:

```
^[^:]*$
```

and using the right regex mode for making them match the beginning/end of string.

Or by using

```
\A[^:]*\Z
```

(assuming C# regex support them).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by beginning/end. I don't allow : in any place in string

Comment: By saying "only match if string has pattern: start of string followed by any number of non-colon chars followed by end of string", you basically end up with a logical equivalent to "contains no colons" (which is what you want).

Comment: Katit, in your original without the *, will only match one character so you want it to repeat. The ^$ at the beginning and end of the above post tell the regex to match start at the beginning of line - repeat and make sure no colon is found in the text till the end of line

Comment: That asterisk (or a plus sign) is key. Without it the original regex is saying that the username must be "exactly one character that is not a colon." @katit - The `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end are special characters that mean the regex doesn't match unless the entire string matches. It's the difference between "contains non-colon characters" and "consists solely of non-colon characters".

Comment: @katit: Regex is often better suited for enforcing the match of a pattern (as in "contains only non-colon characters"), than enforcing the mismatch of a pattern (as in "contains no colon"). So often when you want "forbid x", think in terms of "what else would I end up allowing then?" and write your regex accordingly.

Comment: Great comments guys. Don't know why - regex stuff is just not clicking with me. I will keep trying. ^[^:]*$ worked!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression.  Since you only want to check for the presence of the colon character, simply ensure that

```
UserName.Contains(":")
```

evaluates to `false`.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) for an explanation of `String.Contains`.

Comment: I know about string.contains. However, I want to do attribute-based validations whenever possible

Comment: Which framework or tool is supplying these attribute-based validations?

Comment: DevForce have that. But if I wanted to validate in ASP.NET I can also do same RegexValidation

Comment: @katit I haven't used DevForce, but ASP.NET allows you to build custom validators.  A quick search brought up an old MSDN article about validation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic7

Comment: Yes, it does. I can build custom validator with DevForce too. Why would I if I can achieve that with 1 line regex?

Comment: @katit Which is clearer to someone reading the code: `RegexValidate("[^:]*", ...)` or `DoesNotContainValidate(":", ...)`?  That's enough for me.  Also, I haven't profiled, but I would expect `string.Contains` to be faster than a regular expression match, since regular expressions are much more general than `string.Contains`.

Comment: For this specific use - data entry screen. RegEx doesn't hurt. And I don't have to write DoesNotContainValidate class. Also, it is in a context with error message so it's clear what it does. To me all those regex look like "what the.." But I appreciate it and one day I may start understanging it :)

Comment: @katit I agree that you don't have to write the `DoesNotContainValidate` class, which has all of one or two lines of useful code.  However, my point - which you seem to agree with - is that `DoesNotContainValidate` is much more understandable than a regular expression.

Comment: Maybe it is to some people but like anything else: generics, async coding, etc - some people can and some can't read. I'm fine with using regex even though I can't understand syntax - I know it does what I need.

Comment: @katit I always recommend understanding the code I'm writing, and ideally the code I'm using in a library.  If someone doesn't understand the code they're writing, they run the risk of becoming a cargo cult programmer.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/03/01/82168.aspx for more

Comment: I do not necessary agree with that. I consider regex just like some kind of template. There is a lot of resources for all kind of validation scenarios: Phones, emails, web adresses, etc. I don't need to write function to do it myself - it's kind of given. So, why would you treat this situation with semicolon any different?