# Prohibiting characters - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I prohibit certain characters from being run in a database search by a user of a web application.

E.g. someone enters a username into a web application and I don't want to allow characters such as *semicolons, periods,* or *question marks* to be run behind the scenes when verifying the username.

Thanks

Comment: try checking for c# regex,one example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269792/how-do-i-make-sure-string-does-not-contain-colon-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the characters out of the incoming parameter value with the REPLACE() function.  You will have to nest a REPLACE() function for every character you want to prohibit.